# How can I get contacts back into the inbox?

Tags: gmail

My favorite contacts used to be listed to the left in the inbox, and mailing was a one-step process.  Now, to mail a contact I click on gmail, then contacts, and a new window opens. Then to compose, another window has to open.

Comment: Marikamitsos fixed the problem.   Thank you!          Steve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google is promoting Hangouts, which is now their default settings. You can always revert to the older layout. Look at the bottom left corner of your browser and click on the "*Revert to the old chat*" link

[image: how to revert]

This will take you to your familiar layout:

[image: old chat]